# UWSim install error - not installing osgocean

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to install UWSim

http://www.irs.uji.es/uwsim/wiki/index.php?title=Installing_UWSim

It installs the first 16 packages, but encounters an error when installing osgocean. The message is

```
    [rosmake-2] Starting >>> urdf [ make ]                                                                                                                                  
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< urdf ROS_NOBUILD in package urdf                                                                                                               
[ rosmake ] All 12 lines
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  make wipe
  make[1]: Entering directory `/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/underwater_simulation/osgOcean'
  rm -rf lib
  rm -rf include
  rm -rf share
  rm -rf build
  rm -rf installed
  touch wiped
  touch: cannot touch `wiped': Permission denied
  make[1]: *** [wipe] Error 1
  make[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/underwater_simulation/osgOcean'
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package osgOcean written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/umesh/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120621-163553/osgOcean/build_output.log          
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< osgOcean [FAIL] [ 0.04 seconds ]                                                                                                               
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package osgOcean. 
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.                                                             
[ rosmake ] Results:                                                                                                                                                    
[ rosmake ] Built 17 packages with 1 failures.                                                                                                                          
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory
```

All dependancies are installed.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36971/uwsim-install-error---not-installing-osgocean/) by [umesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2676/umesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2012-06-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [umesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2676/umesh/) on 2012-06-22**:
Solved! it was an md5 sum mismatch. downloaded manually and replaced the tarball.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved! it was an md5 sum mismatch. downloaded manually and replaced the tarball.

---

Originally posted by [umesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2676/umesh/) with karma: 16 on 2012-06-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mario Prats](https://answers.ros.org/users/1616/mario-prats/) on 2012-06-22**:
Good. Anyway, the error seems more related to write permisions under the opt/ folder. You should probably create a ros workspace somewhere under your home folder (http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment#Create_a_ROS_Workspace)